# How can I refer to an interface type in Go?

Tags: types, interface, go

I have these two types:

```
type Routing map[string]Handler

type Handler interface {
    Handle()
}
```

I have a type called `MyHandler` which satisfies the interface, and it looks like this:

```
type MyHandler struct {
}

func (this *MyHandler) Handle() {
    // ...
}
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
// routes is created at the beginning of the program and available
// throughout the lifetime of the script

routes := Routing {
    "/route/here": MyHandler,
})

// ...

// and in another method, this line may be executed several times:

new(routes["/route/here"]).Handle()
```

I get this error on the last line:

> routes["/route/here"] is not a type

When I change that last line to

```
routes["/route/here"].Handle()
```

it obviously works. However, it uses just one instance of the Handler forever... and I wish for a new instance every time that last line is executed. How can I instantiate a new instance of the `Handler` each time that last line is executed?

(I assume that when using `new`, the old ones will be garbage-collected after use. Notice that I'm not saving the instance I create; I only care to call the `Handle()` method then have it destroyed.)

Comment: Maybe `Routing` should be `type Routing map[string](func() Handler)` and then you can put a `NewMyHandler` function into the map that returns a new one each time it's called?

Comment: Good idea. You should have made this an answer!

Comment: I barely know what I'm talking about in Go so I was afraid to :P

Luckily someone else did all the hard work of filling in the details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new()` takes a type as a parameter and returns a pointer to a zeroed out value of that type. Types are not first class values in Go. New is a builtin so it doesn't play by the same rules other code does. New needs to know at compile time what type it will be working on. There is no way to build a map of types.

My suggestion would be to use a function to build each type.

```
type Routing map[string]func() Handler
routes := Routing {
    "/route/here": func() Handler { return new(MyHandler)},
}

routes["/route/here"]().Handle()
```

Instead of building a map of types, we are building a map of functions that return the type we want.

---

Another possibility is to use reflect although I like the function method above better. For this use case I believe it would be an abuse of reflect.

```
type Routing map[string]reflect.Type
routes := Routing {
    "/route/here": reflect.TypeOf(MyHandler{}),
}

reflect.New(routes["/route/here"]).Interface().(Handler).Handle()
```

Warning, this will crash your program if MyHandler does not implement Handler. This method gives up compile time type checking.

Comment: Seems strangely reminiscent of a Javascript-esque way of doing this! I like the first method better, too. Clever use of reflection, though it makes me cringe a bit.

Comment: "There is no way to build a map of types." There is -- use `Type` from the `reflect` module to store a type, and the other functions from the `reflect` module to use it.

Comment: @newacct, that is pretty much what I did in my second example.However, that is not the same thing as having types being types in the language.